# passing dropdownlist value to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html-select

I have dropdown list which display data from the database. I get database data in drop down list but after selecting value in drop down list the selected value I want to pass in controller, then I want to display all detail data of that selected value. But clicking on submit button the selected value of dropdown list is not getting passed to controller.

this is my code

**View: Index.aspx**

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<ApricaCRMEvent.Models.CRM.DatabaseEntities.CRM_Doctor_Request>" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
    SearchIndex
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

<h2>SearchIndex</h2>

    <%--<div id = "SelectDoctors">
          <% Html.RenderPartial("SelectDoctors"); %> 
    </div>--%>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function TestFun() {
            var mdlno = $("#ddlMDLNo").val();
//            $.getJSON("/SearchMDLNo/getMDLNoDetails/" + mdlno, null, function (data) {

//                alert(data.Request_For_Id);
//            });
            var txtmdlno = document.getElementById("Request_For_Id");
            txtmdlno.value = mdlno;
            alert(txtmdlno.value);
        }
</script>

<div>
<h2>Search by MDLNo</h2>
     <% using (Html.BeginForm())
        { %>

         <%: Html.ValidationSummary(true, "Profile Updation was unsuccessful. Please correct the errors and try again.") %>

        Select MDLno 

        <%= Html.DropDownList("ddlMDLNo", ViewData["MDLno"] as SelectList, "--Select One--", new { onchange = "TestFun()" })%> 
        <%: Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Request_For_Id)%>       

         <input type="submit" value="search" name="SearchMDLNo" />    
    <% } %>
</div>


<div> <% Html.RenderPartial("ListDoctors"); %></div>

</asp:Content>
```

**Controller: SearchMDLNoController.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using ApricaCRMEvent.Models.CRM.DataLayer;
using ApricaCRMEvent.Models.CRM.DatabaseEntities;

namespace ApricaCRMEvent.Controllers
{
    public class SearchMDLNoController : Controller
    {
        CRM_Doctor_Request mdlnoObj = new CRM_Doctor_Request();

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewData["MDLno"] = new SelectList(SearchMDLNoDL.getAllMDLno(), "Request_For_Id", "Request_For_Id");
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(CRM_Doctor_Request model)
        {
            ViewData["MDLno"] = new SelectList(SearchMDLNoDL.getAllMDLno(), "Request_For_Id", "Request_For_Id");

            //CRM_Doctor_Request mdlnoObj = SearchMDLNoDL.getMDLData("GJ04_D023");
            //mdlnoObj = SearchMDLNoDL.getMDLData(model.Request_For_Id);
            return View();
        }
        public ActionResult getMDLNoDetails(string id)
        {
            mdlnoObj=SearchMDLNoDL.getMDLData(id);
            return View();
        }
        public ActionResult ListDoctors()
        {
            return View(mdlnoObj);
        }

    }
}
```

this is partial view and in this view selected drop down value .. detail data will be display

**partical View : ListDoctors.ascx**

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<ApricaCRMEvent.Models.CRM.DatabaseEntities.CRM_Doctor_Request>" %>


<div><%: Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Request_For_Id) %></div>

<div>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            Request_For_Id
        </th>
        <th>
            Territory
        </th>
        <th>
            Estimated_Amount
        </th>
        <th>
            Actual_Amount
        </th>
        <th>
            Date_Created
        </th>
        <th>
            Compute_CRM_State
        </th>
        <th>
            Compute_Event_Type
        </th>

    </tr>


    <tr>
        <td>
            <%: Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Request_For_Id) %>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%: Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Territory) %>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%: Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Estimated_Amount) %>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%: Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Actual_Amount) %>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%: Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Date_Created) %>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%: Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Compute_Service_State) %>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%: Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Compute_Event_Type) %>
        </td>
      </tr>


</table>

</div>
```

by selecting value in drop down list and clicking on submit button value is not getting passed. In Index.aspx I have tried some javascript code but it does not work.

---

I have changed something in code. And now this is working.

**View: Index.aspx**

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<ApricaCRMEvent.Models.CRM.DatabaseEntities.CRM_Doctor_Request>" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
    SearchIndex
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

<h2>SearchIndex</h2>

    <%--<div id = "SelectDoctors">
          <% Html.RenderPartial("SelectDoctors"); %> 
    </div>--%>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function TestFun() {
            var mdlno = $("#ddlMDLNo").val();

            var txtmdlno = document.getElementById("Request_For_Id");
            txtmdlno.value = mdlno;
            alert(txtmdlno.value);

        }
</script>

<div>
<h2>Search by MDLNo</h2>
     <% using (Html.BeginForm())
        { %>

         <%: Html.ValidationSummary(true, "Profile Updation was unsuccessful. Please correct the errors and try again.") %>

        Select MDLno 

        <%= Html.DropDownList("ddlMDLNo", ViewData["MDLno"] as SelectList, "--Select One--", new { onchange = "TestFun()" })%> 
        <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Request_For_Id) %>

         <input type="submit" value="search" name="SearchMDLNo" />    
    <% } %>
</div>


<%--<div> <% Html.RenderPartial("ListDoctors"); %></div>--%>
<div>
    <fieldset>
    <legend>CRM_Doctor_Request</legend>

    <div class="display-label">Territory</div>
    <div class="display-field">
        <%: Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Territory) %>
    </div>

    <div class="display-label">CRM_Request_For_Type_Id</div>
    <div class="display-field">
        <%: Html.DisplayFor(model => model.CRM_Request_For_Type_Id) %>
    </div>

    <div class="display-label">Request_For_Id</div>
    <div class="display-field">
        <%: Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Request_For_Id) %>
    </div>

    <div class="display-label">Requestor</div>
    <div class="display-field">
        <%: Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Requestor) %>
    </div>

    <div class="display-label">Division_Id</div>
    <div class="display-field">
        <%: Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Division_Id) %>
    </div>

    <div class="display-label">Suggester</div>
    <div class="display-field">
        <%: Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Suggester) %>
    </div>

    <div class="display-label">Estimated_Amount</div>
    <div class="display-field">
        <%: Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Estimated_Amount) %>
    </div>

    <div class="display-label">Actual_Amount</div>
    <div class="display-field">
        <%: Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Actual_Amount) %>
    </div>

    <div class="display-label">Priority</div>
    <div class="display-field">
        <%: Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Priority) %>
    </div>

    <div class="display-label">CRM_Service_Type_Id</div>
    <div class="display-field">
        <%: Html.DisplayFor(model => model.CRM_Service_Type_Id) %>
    </div>

    <div class="display-label">Deadline</div>
    <div class="display-field">
        <%: Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Deadline) %>
    </div>

    <div class="display-label">Executed_Date</div>
    <div class="display-field">
        <%: Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Executed_Date) %>
    </div>

    <div class="display-label">Entry_Done_By</div>
    <div class="display-field">
        <%: Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Entry_Done_By) %>
    </div>

    <div class="display-label">Date_Created</div>
    <div class="display-field">
        <%: Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Date_Created) %>
    </div>

    <div class="display-label">Date_Modified</div>
    <div class="display-field">
        <%: Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Date_Modified) %>
    </div>

    <div class="display-label">Event_Type_Id</div>
    <div class="display-field">
        <%: Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Event_Type_Id) %>
    </div>

    <div class="display-label">Compute_Event_Type</div>
    <div class="display-field">
        <%: Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Compute_Event_Type) %>
    </div>

    <div class="display-label">CRM_State_Id</div>
    <div class="display-field">
        <%: Html.DisplayFor(model => model.CRM_State_Id) %>
    </div>

    <div class="display-label">Compute_CRM_State</div>
    <div class="display-field">
        <%: Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Compute_CRM_State) %>
    </div>

    <div class="display-label">Service_State_Id</div>
    <div class="display-field">
        <%: Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Service_State_Id) %>
    </div>

    <div class="display-label">Compute_Service_State</div>
    <div class="display-field">
        <%: Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Compute_Service_State) %>
    </div>

    <div class="display-label">Is_Active</div>
    <div class="display-field">
        <%: Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Is_Active) %>
    </div>

    <div class="display-label">Comment</div>
    <div class="display-field">
        <%: Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Comment) %>
    </div>
</fieldset>


</div>
</asp:Content>
```

**Controller: SearchMDLNoController.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using ApricaCRMEvent.Models.CRM.DataLayer;
using ApricaCRMEvent.Models.CRM.DatabaseEntities;

namespace ApricaCRMEvent.Controllers
{
    public class SearchMDLNoController : Controller
    {
        CRM_Doctor_Request mdlnoObj = new CRM_Doctor_Request();

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewData["MDLno"] = new SelectList(SearchMDLNoDL.getAllMDLno(), "Request_For_Id", "Request_For_Id");
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(CRM_Doctor_Request model)
        {
            ViewData["MDLno"] = new SelectList(SearchMDLNoDL.getAllMDLno(), "Request_For_Id", "Request_For_Id");

            //CRM_Doctor_Request mdlnoObj = SearchMDLNoDL.getMDLData("GJ04_D023");
            //mdlnoObj = SearchMDLNoDL.getMDLData(model.Request_For_Id);
            mdlnoObj = SearchMDLNoDL.getMDLData(model.Request_For_Id);
            return View(mdlnoObj);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Put a debugger in TestFun() and check whether `mdlno` is getting any value of the dropdown or not

Comment: yes whatever value I select in drop down it alert me that value through this : <script type="text/javascript">
        function TestFun() {
            var mdlno = $("#ddlMDLNo").val();            var txtmdlno = document.getElementById("Request_For_Id");
            txtmdlno.value = mdlno;
            alert(txtmdlno.value);
        }
</script>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
$.getJSON("/SearchMDLNo/getMDLNoDetails",{id : mdlno}, function (data) {
         alert(data.Request_For_Id);
});
```

This should work for you

---

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function TestFun() {
            var mdlno = $("#ddlMDLNo").val();
            $.ajax({
              type: 'POST',
              dataType: 'json',
              data: {id: mdlno},
              success: function(result){
                      alert('success');
              }
            });
        }
</script>
```

Then in your controller change it like this:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult getMDLNoDetails(string id)
    {
        mdlnoObj=SearchMDLNoDL.getMDLData(id);
        return Json(true);
    }
```

Comment: did you check at your controller's Action end by placing debugger to the action method?

Comment: Yeah I have tried that also by putting debugging point. The only thing is that it is showing null. It means value is not passing to controller by clicking on submit button.

Comment: I have done some changes in my code and it is working now. I  am getting detail data of selected drop down value. but I want it in different view like my 1st code is post. But it was not working So I took it in same one view. What to do to take in different view?

Comment: probably passing url parameter to ajax would change view

Comment: @Anu You have removed entire ajax call and how can you post the data to controller?

Comment: @Anu That's fine ! But make it as `HiddenFor` instead of `TextBoxFor`, it will be better if you dont want to show your content